# Macbook not updating time zone

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, system-settings

I flew from Washington DC to Devon (UK) roughly 9 hours ago.

My MacBook knows that I am in the UK, but won't update the timezone.

[image]

How do I make sure that the MacBook keeps updating the time zone automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you 'unlocked' the pref pane with the icon at the bottom left.

You could try using the Terminal command `sudo ntpdate -u time.euro.apple.com`.

If the command returns errors such as `Can't find host` or `no servers can be used`, the network you're connecting to might have a firewall block on ntp servers.

Comment: Running that command seems to update it to the American time